# Showing Json response in `RecyclerView` using `CardView` in Android Studio in Java

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have to show my JSON response in a recycler view using card view with use of volley library .My JSON response is something like

```
{
"id": 87,
"parent_id": 0,
"shipping": {
    "first_name": "JPbrajesh",
    "last_name": "kumar",
            },
"payment_method": "COD",
"line_items": [
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "abc",
        "price": 85
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "zxc",
        "price": 38
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "asd",
        "price": 136
    }
            ],
"tax_lines": [],
"shipping_lines": [
    {
        "id": 19,
    }
],
"fee_lines": [],
"_links": {
    "self": [
        {
            "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/87"
        }
    ],
    "collection": [
        {
            "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders"
        }
    ]
}
```

}
`i have to show (Line_items) in a recycler view using **volley Library**.Please provide some related steps.Thankyou in advance for kind support.

Comment: you should try to follow some tutorials for online, and when you have a good decent amount of java code, im sure everyone would be willing to help.

Comment: Where are you having trouble. Parsing JSON? Creating an `Adapter`? Creating a layout? All of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can first create a class `LineItem` as model for lineitems.
2. Then in the activity where you want the data to be used, create a list of line items and fill that list with data from you json object.
3. create a layout for that lineitem
4. create an adapter class
5. declare the adapter and pass it the list and then attach the adapter to the recyclerview.

Something like this: 
`ProductCategory` class

```java
package com.pesabay.pesabay;

/**
 * Created by Valentin_Kavakure on 20-Jun-17.
 */

public class ProductCategory {
    private int id,niveau,order,premier,nbrProduits;
    private String name;
    private String image;

    public ProductCategory() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ProductCategory(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Then the layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bluebg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The adapter:

```java
public class CatGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatGridAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ProductCategory> categoryList;
    private Context context;
    private RecyclerViewClickListener recyclerViewClickListener;

    public void setRecyclerViewClickListener(RecyclerViewClickListener recyclerViewClickListener) {
        this.recyclerViewClickListener = recyclerViewClickListener;
    }

    public CatGridAdapter(List<ProductCategory> categoryList, Context context) {
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.category_grid_layout,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(categoryList.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;TextView title;
        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (recyclerViewClickListener!=null) {
                         recyclerViewClickListener.recyclerViewItemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And the in my activity:

```java
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_data);
        categoryList=new ArrayList<>();
        catGridAdapter=new CatGridAdapter(categoryList,CategoryGrid.this);
        pg=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pg);
        catGridAdapter.setRecyclerViewClickListener(new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void recyclerViewItemClicked(View view, int position) {
                /* some code*/
        });
        gridLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(CategoryGrid.this,2);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(catGridAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Volley is the library for request the information. When Volley succeed, you get this this JSON response. After that, you need to parse Line_items and pass them to the RecyclerView Adapter.

Hope it helps.